# Who is the voice actor for this character in the opening cinematic of Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've just re-installed Starcraft 2 and I had the pleasure to view the nice intro cinematic ;)

The voice of the non-prison-person-speaking really reminded me of Peter Cullen.

As I couldn't find any info on that, I'd like to know if anyone actually knows who that voice actor is and why he sounds like Cullen :)

Comment: IMDb, it's not just for movies. [StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty (Video Game 2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1037854/)

Comment: I added a tag for voice-acting, as I think it could be a nice one to help discuss voice actors and actresses, a fun topic. Someone remove the tag or edit it if you feel otherwise.

Comment: @NickT I know, thanks. But I don't know which character is speaking in the intro :p

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag, Wikwocket. I hope this doesn't bring us to another discussion on questions of nature "name the voice-actor in this game" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guy who did the voice acting is [James Harper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Harper_%28actor%29), he plays the character

> "Arcturus Mengsk".

Comment: @Fabian, A villain who existed in the first game and is introduced in the first mission is hardly a spoiler.

Comment: But the identity of the voice in the intro isn't revealed until later, or am I badly misremembering that? If I'm wrong just roll back my edit.

Comment: I can't remember now actually. I recognized him instantly from the first game as the voice actor is the same. edit: changed spelling.

Comment: thanks a lot. didnt spoil anything for me - never really payed attention to the story to be honest :)

Comment: On the plus side, it taught me about stackexchange's new spoiler functionality!

Comment: @Fabian: I recognized his voice *instantly* and then wondered for half the game why it was never revisited. But I played way too much starcraft I in my day.